# Java script só funciona no primeiro elemento do HTML

Tags: javascript

Criei uma seção de divs com botão de aparecer e desaparecer o conteúdo das divs ao ser clicado, o script e o html funcionam perfeitamente porém só pro primeiro elemento, quando clico nos demais botões ele altera somente o primeiro elemento. Tipo o java script só funciona para o primeiro Elemento que é encontrado no HTML

A estrutura é essa

```js
$(function(){
        $(".btn-toggle").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
            el = $(this).data('element');
            $(el).toggle();
        });
    });
```

```css
.btn-toggle{border:1px solid;}

.btn-toggle:hover{background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#minhaDiv">Mostrar / Esconder</button>

<div class="m1" id="minhaDiv">Conteudo 1</div>

<button type="button" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#minhaDiv">Mostrar / Esconder</button>

<div class="m2" id="minhaDiv">Conteudo 2</div>
```

Oque está faltando? Queria que quando clicasse no primeiro elemento mostrasse o conteúdo normal e quando clicar no segundo abrisse o segundo conteúdo da segunda div normal também como se fosse um Acordion.

Comment: Boas-vindas. Para continuarmos dentro da [finalidade do site](/help) é importante você [edit] a pergunta e trocar o código fornecido por um [mcve] do problema, de forma a facilitar a identificação e servir como referência para futuros visitantes. *Agradecemos a compreensão*.

Comment: **Os comentários foram [movidos para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147443/); por favor, não continuem a discussão aqui**. Antes de postar um comentário abaixo deste, por favor, revise os propósitos dos comentários. Os comentários que não solicitam esclarecimentos ou sugerem melhorias geralmente cabem como resposta, no Stack Overflow em Português Meta, ou no Chat do Stack Overflow em Português. Comentários continuando a discussão podem ser removidos.